# "invalid opcode. The execution might have thrown." Error

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

The below contract compiles and can be deployed. But when I try to transact using the createProject function, I obtain an error as follows:

> transact to Details.createProject errored: VM error: invalid opcode.

> invalid opcode

> The execution might have thrown.

I am trying to create a smart contract which stores the details (name and description) of a project. My smart contract code is as follows:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17; 

contract Details {
    
    // Id number of the project 
    uint public projcount = 0;    
    
    struct Projects {
        string projectname;
        string description;
    }

    // A mapping from a student's address to projects he/she is associated with
    mapping (address => Projects[]) public Proj;
       
    // Storing the project name and description obtained from input as strings
    function createProject (string memory _projectname, string memory _description) public {
        Proj[msg.sender][projcount].projectname = _projectname;
        Proj[msg.sender][projcount].description = _description;
        projcount++;
    }
    
    // Retrieving the project details stored using student's address and project id number
    function getProject (address _addr, uint _id) public view returns (string, string) {
        return (Proj[_addr][_id].projectname, Proj[_addr][_id].description);
    } 
}
```

Please let me know what could be possible fix. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    // Storing the project name and description obtained from input as strings
    function createProject (string memory _projectname, string memory _description) public {
        Projects storage p;
        p.projectname = _projectname;
        p.description = _description;
        Proj[msg.sender].push(p);
        projcount++;
    }
```

Comment: Using the "storage" keyword gives a warning: "Uninitialized storage pointer p", but compiles. When executed, it says transaction pending and the page (remix) becomes unresponsive. I tried replacing the "storage" keyword with "memory" and it worked. But I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: using memory instead of storage is more suitable